# Objective-C Blocks - use as an object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

With reference to the code below, once a block has been put into an array, how could you take that block object and run the actual code in the block.

Another Question: If I call a method in a block like below, does that block encapsulate the code in that method or capture the signature of the method and call it that way?

```
-(void)blockCalledMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}

-(void)programStart
{       

    NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[^ { [self blockCalledMethod];} copy] autorelease],nil];    

    id pointerToBlock = [array lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
void (^pointerToBlock)(void) = [array lastObject];
pointerToBlock(); // because ^ {} is void(^)(void)
```

You cannot declare `pointerToBlock` as an `id` if you want to call it directly, because the compiler has to recognize it as a block type and not just *an* object.

> If I call a method in a block like above, does that block encapsulate the code in that method or capture the signature of the method and call it that way?

I should think `self` refers to the calling class.

Comment: @BoltClock, I also believe that `^{}` is not the same as `nil` so you can't test for it's existence like that, correct?  `if (pointerToBlock)` is bad?  Blocks aren't subclasses of NSObjects, although they can be stored in containers and treated as such?

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: I was referring to `^ {}` as a signature, but yes, a block is not the same as no block (nil). Per your second question, I tried `[^ {} isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]` and (to my surprise) it returns `YES`.

Comment: `if (pointerToBlock)` should work fine.  In fact, if `pointerToBlock` is NULL (same thing as nil), if you do `pointerToBlock()` you'll crash, unlike messaging a nil object, so you'll want to do this check before calling a block if it can be NULL.

Comment: If I call a method in a block like above, does that block encapsulate the code in that method or capture the signature of the method and call it that way?

Comment: @Daniel *thats* what it was!  you can't call a `^{}` block like you can call a `nil` NSObject.  Thanks guys.  sorry to piggy-back here.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: Not a problem, always good to stir extra constructive discussion :)

Comment: @Stephan: Note that ^{} and NULL are not the same thing. I'm pretty sure you _can_ call ^{} -- that is a block that does nothing -- but you can't call NULL.

Comment: `self` refers to the object where the block was defined, i.e. whatever `self` is inside of the `programStart` method.  Note that `self` gets retained in this case, [potentially creating a retain cycle](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-30-dealing-with-retain-cycles.html)